# Xamarin.formsでQRコードリーダーを作成

Tags: c#, opencv, xamarin

Xamarin.formsでandroid,iOS向けにQRコードリーダーを作成しようとしております。

OpenCVSharp4を使用を考えており、OpenCVSharp4をNuGetからインストールしましたが、

```
System.DllNotFoundException: 'OpenCvSharpExtern assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)'
```

のようなエラーが出てしまいます。

なにか解決策や代替案等ありましたら、ご教示お願いいたします。

Comment: OpenCVSharp4は動作OS用ネイティブバインディングが必要だけど、iOS,Androidは未サポートのようですね。[shimat/opencvsharp](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp) iOS,Android両方で使いたいならZXing.Net.Mobileとかでは？[【Xamarin.Forms】QRコードの読み取りをする方法](https://takataka430.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/03/21/184259), [Scanning QR codes with Xamarin.Forms](https://www.lindseybroos.be/2020/02/scanning-qr-codes-with-xamarin-forms/) またはC/C++のライブラリで個別に対応する方法があるかも?[How to use OpenCV from Xamarin (Android and iOS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54260093/9014308), [Xamarin.Forms(Android) から OpenCV(C/C++) を利用する](https://qiita.com/hsytkm/items/73a8057e001dda72b6d2)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。ZXing.Net.Mobileはすでに試しており、動作することも確認しています。ただ、認識率が少し低いのとQRコードが少し間隔を空けて複数並んでいることを想定しており、画面に写っている範囲の一部だけをスキャンするエリアにできないのがネックとなっておりOpenCVで対応できないものかと考えておりました。

Comment: 認識率とか性能が気になるなら、元々のデンソ－ウェーブの技術が無料かもしくは低価格で使えるかどうか聞いてみてはどうでしょう？ [クルクル - QRコードリーダー](https://www.denso-wave.com/ja/system/qr/product/reader.html)

Comment: ありがとうございます。色々と検討させていただきます。